# Upgrade from 2.3.4 to 2.4.4 errir: Class 'Laminas\Code\Scanner\FileScanner' not found#0

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

We are upgrading Magento 2 from 2.3.4 to 2.4.4, but are getting the following error when running setup:upgrade.

Anyone having an idea why we get this error?

Best regards,
Jesper

Class 'Laminas\Code\Scanner\FileScanner' not found#0 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#1 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#3 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php(561): spl_autoload_call()
#4 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php(672): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor->getAliasMapping()
#5 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php(550): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor->resolveFullyQualifiedClas                          sName()
#6 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/MethodsMap.php(146): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor->getParamType()
#7 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Communication/Config/ReflectionGenerator.php(50): Magento\Framework\Reflection\MethodsMap->getMethodPara                          ms()
#8 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Communication/Config/ReflectionGenerator.php(79): Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\ReflectionGener                          ator->extractMethodMetadata()
#9 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi-async/Code/Generator/Config/RemoteServiceReader/Communication.php(71): Magento\Framework\Communicati                          on\Config\ReflectionGenerator->generateTopicConfigForServiceMethod()
#10 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Communication/Config/CompositeReader.php(55): Magento\WebapiAsync\Code\Generator\Config\RemoteServiceRe                          ader\Communication->read()
#11 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Data.php(105): Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\CompositeReader->read()
#12 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Data.php(93): Magento\Framework\Config\Data->initData()
#13 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Communication/Config/Data.php(29): Magento\Framework\Config\Data->__construct()
#14 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Data->__construc                          t()
#15 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactor                          y->createObject()
#16 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create(                          )
#17 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#18 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->resolveArgument()
#19 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->getResolvedArgument()
#20 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactor                          y->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#21 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Develo                          per->_resolveArguments()
#22 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create(                          )
#23 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#24 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->resolveArgument()
#25 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->getResolvedArgument()
#26 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactor                          y->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#27 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Develo                          per->_resolveArguments()
#28 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create(                          )
#29 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(206): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#30 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(217): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->parseArray()
#31 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(182): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->parseArray()
#32 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->resolveArgument()
#33 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->getResolvedArgument()
#34 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactor                          y->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#35 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Develo                          per->_resolveArguments()
#36 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create(                          )
#37 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#38 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->resolveArgument()
#39 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->getResolvedArgument()
#40 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactor                          y->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#41 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Develo                          per->_resolveArguments()
#42 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create(                          )
#43 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(206): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#44 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(217): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->parseArray()
#45 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(182): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->parseArray()
#46 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->resolveArgument()
#47 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->getResolvedArgument()
#48 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactor                          y->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#49 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Develo                          per->_resolveArguments()
#50 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create(                          )
#51 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#52 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->resolveArgument()
#53 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->getResolvedArgument()
#54 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactor                          y->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#55 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Develo                          per->_resolveArguments()
#56 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create(                          )
#57 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#58 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->resolveArgument()
#59 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->getResolvedArgument()
#60 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactor                          y->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#61 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Develo                          per->_resolveArguments()
#62 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create(                          )
#63 /home/name_dev/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/MessageQueue/Config/Proxy.php(84): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#64 /home/name_dev/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/MessageQueue/Config/Proxy.php(151): Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Config\Proxy->_getSubject()
#65 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/Config/Topology/ConfigReaderPlugin.php(70): Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Config\Proxy->                          getBinds()
#66 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/Config/Topology/ConfigReaderPlugin.php(47): Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Config\Topolog                          y\ConfigReaderPlugin->getTopologyConfigDataFromQueueConfig()
#67 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Config\Topology\ConfigReaderPlugin->a                          fterRead()
#68 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Topology\Config\CompositeReader\Inter                          ceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
#69 /home/name_dev/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/MessageQueue/Topology/Config/CompositeReader/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\MessageQueu                          e\Topology\Config\CompositeReader\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#70 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Data.php(105): Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Topology\Config\CompositeReader\Interceptor->read(                          )
#71 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Data.php(93): Magento\Framework\Config\Data->initData()
#72 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/Topology/Config/Data.php(24): Magento\Framework\Config\Data->**construct()
#73 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Topology\Config\Data->**                          construct()
#74 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactor                          y->createObject()
#75 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create(                          )
#76 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#77 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->resolveArgument()
#78 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->getResolvedArgument()
#79 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactor                          y->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#80 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Develo                          per->_resolveArguments()
#81 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create(                          )
#82 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#83 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->resolveArgument()
#84 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->getResolvedArgument()
#85 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactor                          y->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#86 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Develo                          per->_resolveArguments()
#87 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create(                          )
#88 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#89 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->resolveArgument()
#90 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->getResolvedArgument()
#91 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactor                          y->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#92 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Develo                          per->_resolveArguments()
#93 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create(                          )
#94 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#95 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->resolveArgument()
#96 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory                          ->getResolvedArgument()
#97 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactor                          y->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#98 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Develo                          per->_resolveArguments()
#99 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create(                          )
#100 /home/name_dev/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1215): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create()
#101 /home/name_dev/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1622): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->createSchemaDataHandler()
#102 /home/name_dev/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1114): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->getSchemaDataHandler()
#103 /home/name_dev/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(895): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData()
#104 /home/name_dev/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/UpgradeCommand.php(146): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema()
#105 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand->execute()
#106 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#107 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#108 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#109 /home/name_dev/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#110 /home/name_dev/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()

Comment: Could be different things, try to delete generated/*, flush redis, clean caches and try bin/magento setup:upgrade again

Comment: This was caused by a missing setup folder in Magento. The soludtion was to remove Magento from composer.json, run composer update, add magento to composer.json again and rund composer update.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the vendor directory and launch the terminal again and execute the command

```
composer install
```

to regenerate all the Magento standard codes. You can check your vendor folder to make sure laminas are installed and run the compilation command later to load the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, it worked for me. I'm pretty sure you just saved me several hours of cursing!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. I downloaded and replaced setup https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4.5/setup
folder to the project folder and the error has disappeared.